# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to model class android

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit, linkedhashmap

I am passing the response of an `API` call (`Retrofit` used) to a class and trying to cast it to my model class. Since i am using **retrofit** for the `API` call, it generates a linked hashmap based on the response from the server prior to convert it into model class object using **Gson**. (That is what i understand, correct me if i am wrong). I have attached an image of what i can see when i **debug** with the response object. How can i convert this response into an object of my model class or type Object. **I am getting class cast exception when i attempt to cast type Object into my model class inside my activity.**

Here is my code

### API Call

```
call.enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            if (response.body() != null) {   
                        List<CategoriesBaseModel> categoryBaseResponseList = (List<CategoriesBaseModel>) response.body();
                        List<Object> categoryResponseList = (List<Object>) categoryBaseResponseList.get(0).getData();
                        if (categoryResponseList != null) {
                           mCategoriesInterface.passCategoriesResponse(categoryResponseList, "HomeFragment");
                        }
            }                
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {

            call.cancel();
        }
    });
```

### Activity

```
CategoriesInterface categoriesInterface = new CategoriesInterface() {
    @Override
    public void passCategoriesResponse(List<Object> scheduleList, String name) {
        CategoriesModel categoriesModel;
        for (Object model : scheduleList){
            categoriesModel = (CategoriesModel) model;
            Log.d("TAG", "");
        }
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: see this page, perheaps he give you an answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444863/google-gson-linkedtreemap-class-cast-to-myclass

Comment: Does the error occur exactly on this line?: `categoriesModel = (CategoriesModel) model;`

Comment: @gil.fernandes Yes. Exactly on the same line

Comment: The problem is it cannot be accessed as a hash map and the exception raises if i cast object

Comment: Whilst this is not a great solution: you can convert manually the `LinkedTreeMap` to a `CategoriesModel` object. That is definitely possible,  but not the most elegant solution. You can just go and cast the `model` object to a `java.util.Map` and then happily get each field.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by converting the Object into Json string and coverting it back directly to the model class object.

```
Gson gs = new Gson();
String js = gs.toJson(model);
categoriesModel = gs.fromJson(js, CategoriesModel.class);
```

Comment: Whilst the code is compact, this is not a very performant option. You serialize and then deserialize. It might not make much difference, if you do not have much data, but if you do, this is quite bad for performance.