# How to deserialize json string of 3-level typed object in Kotlin?

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I am using Gson library to serialize/deserialize objects, but when I try to deserialize object like this `List<Triple<String, String, DateTime>>` I've got `List<Triple<String, String, LinkedTreeMap>>` although IDEA confidently says it's `DatTime` and not `LinkedTreeMap`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using the plug-in Json to data classes?

Comment: No, I am not using it.

Comment: Try it, maybe solve your problem

Comment: Can you post a link please?

Comment: You can find it directly from Android studio plugin settings: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass

Comment: Actually I don't see how it can help me in this situation. My json which I'm trying to convert to object is correct.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444863/google-gson-linkedtreemap-class-cast-to-myclass/32494079