# Parse HashMap<String, ArrayList<User>> with Gson throws java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, parse-error

I have a Json like this:

```
{
    "a": [
        {"name": "a"}
    ],
    "b": [
        {"name": "b"}
    ]
}
```

And i use **Retrofit** for convert to java object like this:

```
public interface TheService {
    @GET("data")
    Call<HashMap<String, ArrayList<User>>> getUsers();
}
```

It's work fine. But when i cache my json string and parse it manually with Gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
HashMap<String, ArrayList<User>> map = gson.fromJson(jsonString, HashMap.class);
```

It throws error: **java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to xxx.User**

So how can i covert jsonString to `HashMap<String, ArrayList<User>>` object with Gson?

Comment: Hope this one helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/how-can-i-convert-json-to-a-hashmap-using-gson

Comment: I found solution here with TypeToken: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32494079/1472483

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here: (Detailed explain) https://stackoverflow.com/a/32494079/1472483

With using TypeToken

```
Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, ArrayList<User>>>() {}.getType();
HashMap<String, ArrayList<User>> map = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```